# Strip trailing unit using regex

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say the original text is something like this:

`12345 {unit}`

Then what's the regex pattern for removing `{unit}` part and only keeping the numbers? Note that the length of `unit` can be random. Thanks.

EDIT:
well I had thought about using \d+, but I guess it would fail if the number part contains some kind of separators, e.g. 1000 separator. So if the number looks like this, 12,345 then the pattern \d probably wont work.

Comment: Would a simple \d+ work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string extractValue(string input) {
  var result=Regex.Match(input,@"(\d+(?:,\d{3})*)\s";
  return (result.Success) ? result.Groups[0].Value : null;
}
```

This function will return null on failure to match otherwise the matched value string.

You could also then parse the result through int.parse to get an int

```
int? extractIntValue(string input) {
  var result=Regex.Match(input,@"(\d+(?:,\d{3})*)\s";
  if (result.Success) return int.Parse(result.Groups[0].Value,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands|System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer);
  return null;
}
```

If the result could be decimal (as opposed to integer then the match line would read

```
  var result=Regex.Match(input,@"(\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+))\s";
```

If you were using the decimal value you would then use the appropriate decimal.parse method

Answer (score 1):

If you always have that format, I guess you don't have to use a RegExp. You could split the string on the space, an take what was before the space as your number.

```
string original = "12345 {unit}";
string[] parts = original.Split(' ');
string yourNumber = parts[0];
```

Comment: well the thing is it's not a specific function that only deals with that case. It also quite often receives regular strings, like normal sentences.

Comment: Possibly use `input.Split(new[] {' '},2);` instead to limit the split to two strings

Comment: @woodykiddy I see, yeah in that case my answer would give you no luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] sa = 
  { "12345 {unit}", "12345{unit}", "-123.45{unit}","-1,023.45{unit}",
    "12345 cm", "99%", "99.1 %", "0.1234{unit}","-0.1234{unit}",
    "12345", "123.45", "12,345.67 {unit}"
  };

foreach (string s in sa) {
  Console.WriteLine("Numeric=[" + Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\d]+$", "") + "], Unit=[" + Regex.Match(s, @"[^\d]+$") + "]");
}
```

My logic is to detect the none numeric at the back of the value only. The negative sign (-), comma, dot in the front and middle will remain intact.

This generic logic can be used to strip value only or unit only.

```
Numeric=[12345], Unit=[ {unit}]
Numeric=[12345], Unit=[{unit}]
Numeric=[-123.45], Unit=[{unit}]
Numeric=[-1,023.45], Unit=[{unit}]
Numeric=[12345], Unit=[ cm]
Numeric=[99], Unit=[%]
Numeric=[99.1], Unit=[ %]
Numeric=[0.1234], Unit=[{unit}]
Numeric=[-0.1234], Unit=[{unit}]
Numeric=[12345], Unit=[]
Numeric=[123.45], Unit=[]
Numeric=[12,345.67], Unit=[ {unit}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Match(input, @"([0-9]+) ")
```

or

```
Regex.Match(input, @"(\d+) ")
```

will match only the number part

Comment: As per OP there is a space between the number and the unit part... Space will be matched but won't be part of the match group

Answer (score 0):

What exactly the "unit" part consists of? Can it have numbers in it? If no, then this may work:

```
string numberPart = Regex.Match(@"\d+").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, a simple string manipulation can be sufficient. Taking the starting digits sequence:

```
string text = "12345 {unit}";
string result = new string (text.Trim().TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the number, only when there's the `{unit}` part you can use this pattern:

```
(\d+)(?:\s+\{\w+\})
```

`?:` means that it won't capture the space and the unit.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `[0-9][,0-9]+[0-9]` should do the trick. This will accept digits and comma as a seperator.